# IabHelper class not working?

Tags: android, android-intent, in-app-purchase

I have implemented the IabHelper class in my android project and it says that the 'getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus' cannot be resolved. The full method:

```
buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(5,
mContext.getPackageName(),oldSkus, sku, itemType, extraData);
```

I implemented in app billing in my project but I have not yet created any items to be purchased, though the rest of the methods don't have any problems.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The aidl in Google's example project is different than the aidl file included in the extra 'Google Play Billing' SDK. I have no idea why they thought that was a good idea. Just replace the aidl in your project with the one included in the example project. This contains the missing method references. You can also copy and paste the below code into your aidl file at the bottom:

```
    /**
 * This API is currently under development.
 */
int stub(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type);

/**
 * Returns a pending intent to launch the purchase flow for upgrading or downgrading a
 * subscription. The existing owned SKU(s) should be provided along with the new SKU that
 * the user is upgrading or downgrading to.
 * @param apiVersion billing API version that the app is using, must be 5 or later
 * @param packageName package name of the calling app
 * @param oldSkus the SKU(s) that the user is upgrading or downgrading from,
 *        if null or empty this method will behave like {@link #getBuyIntent}
 * @param newSku the SKU that the user is upgrading or downgrading to
 * @param type of the item being purchased, currently must be "subs"
 * @param developerPayload optional argument to be sent back with the purchase information
 * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
 *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, appropriate response codes
 *                         on failures.
 *         "BUY_INTENT" - PendingIntent to start the purchase flow
 *
 * The Pending intent should be launched with startIntentSenderForResult. When purchase flow
 * has completed, the onActivityResult() will give a resultCode of OK or CANCELED.
 * If the purchase is successful, the result data will contain the following key-value pairs
 *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, appropriate response
 *                         codes on failures.
 *         "INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA" - String in JSON format similar to
 *                                 '{"orderId":"12999763169054705758.1371079406387615",
 *                                   "packageName":"com.example.app",
 *                                   "productId":"exampleSku",
 *                                   "purchaseTime":1345678900000,
 *                                   "purchaseToken" : "122333444455555",
 *                                   "developerPayload":"example developer payload" }'
 *         "INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE" - String containing the signature of the purchase data that
 *                                  was signed with the private key of the developer
 *                                  TODO: change this to app-specific keys.
 */
Bundle getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus(int apiVersion, String packageName,
    in List<String> oldSkus, String newSku, String type, String developerPayload);
```

Comment: Don't forget to rebuild the project once you replaced/edited the file. Without rebuilding it, the error will not go away and you may think the problem is not solved...